# How to create object from two different fs methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

I want to create object with filename and fileStat so in below code i am checking stats with async and for filename i used readDir now once i have values how can i create array of object ? I am trying to get filename and its created date and send it the client `objToReturn`. Any idea how can i acheive that task ?

app.js

```
function readDirectory(callback) {
    var dirPath = './logs/ditLogs';
    //this will get you list of all files. in directory
    var files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);
    var objToReturn = [{
        fileName: '',
        fileStat: ''
    }];
    //then using async do like this
    async.eachSeries(files, function(file, callback) {
        var filePath = path.join(dirPath, file);
        fs.stat(filePath, function(err, stats) {
            objToReturn.fileStat = stats;
            //write stats data into objToReturn
            fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {
                objToReturn.filename = items;
            });

            callback();
        });
    }, function(err) {
        //final callback when all files completed here send objToReturn to client
        callback(objToReturn);
    });
```

Comment: mean you want to store `stats` and `items` in an array?

Comment: yes array of object stats and items for each file in directory

Comment: You should accept the answer if it works.

Comment: filename is only added to first file in the array but that is also undefined

Comment: are you getting valid value in `stats` and `items`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I see what you're trying to do here. You want to read all of the file paths in the given directory and then for each file, collect information before returning this information to a given callback. It appears right now that you are adding these props to the array `objToReturn`, instead of to each object and pushing it to `objToReturn`. In this way, you overwrite the properties on each async read.

You also use `fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {` where I think you mean to refer to `filePath` that you declare earlier.

Try something like:

```
async.eachSeries(files, function(file, callback) {
    var filePath = path.join(dirPath, file);
    var fileInfo = {};
    fs.stat(filePath, function(err, stats) {
        fileInfo.fileStat = stats;
        //write stats data into objToReturn
        fs.readdir(filePath, function(err, items) {
            fileInfo.filename = items;
        });
        objToReturn.push(fileInfo);
        callback();
    });
}, function(err) {
```

Comment: getting an error ` fileInfo.push(fileInfo);
TypeError: fileInfo.push is not a function`

Comment: i fixed error but i only see file stats i dont see filenames in object , Any idea ?

Comment: The Javascript Object doesn't have .push(), only an array. Since your above code shows fileInfo defined as an empty object, that makes sense. Try pushing to an array `[]` instead.

Could you edit your answer to include your more recent code? It's hard to debug not knowing what's changed. Also try to log `items` before you assign it to that object.

Comment: hmm All filenames are part of first index in array like this ` filename: [  'server.log', 'server1.log' ] },`

Comment: is it possible to make sure file stats are for same filename that is part of object ?

Comment: Thanks for the help i sort out the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function readDirectory(callback) {
    var dirPath = './logs/ditLogs';

    //this will get you list of all files. in directory
    var files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);
    var objToReturn = [];

    //then using async do like this
    async.eachSeries(files, function(file, callback) {
        var filePath = path.join(dirPath, file);

        fs.stat(filePath, function(err, stats) {
            objToReturn.fileStat = stats;

            //write stats data into objToReturn
            fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {
                objToReturn.filename = items;
                objToReturn.push({
                    fileName: items,
                    fileStat: stats
                })
            });

            callback();
        });
    }, function(err) {
        //final callback when all files completed here send objToReturn to client
        callback(objToReturn);
    });
}
```

Hope this should work.